# Unable to get both RA and DHCP6 address on a particular nic

Tags: networking, ipv6, autoconf

My host is connected to a network that is connected to Router and DHCP6 server.
radvd.conf setting on the router is given below:

```
interface eth1
{
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   AdvManagedFlag on;
   AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
   prefix fc00:192:168:30::/64
   {
            AdvOnLink on;
            AdvAutonomous on;
            AdvRouterAddr off;
   };

};
```

dhcp6s.conf setting:

```
interface eth1{
server preference 255;
renew-time 360;
rebind-time 450;
prefer-life-time 500;
valid-life-time 500;
allow rapid-commit;
link AAA{
   range fc00:192:168:20::100 to fc00:192:268:20::200/64;
   prefix fc00:192:168:20::/64;
};
};
```

In Ubuntu 14.04 client host:
In /etc/sysctl.conf file Added :

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1
```

In /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface eth1 inet manual
iface eth1 inet6 auto
```

When I am setting "iface eth1 inet6 auto" I am getting only RA address(fc00:192:168:30::/64) and if I am setting "iface eth1 inet6 dhcp" I am getting dhcp6 address (fc00:192:168:20::/64).

Please let me know is there any way using which I can get both RA and DHCP6 addresses on eth1.

Thanks in advance,
Shruti